# How to hide the iTerm icon from status menu?

Tags: icon, menu-bar, iterm

How can I remove the iTerm icon from the status bar menu? I'm not sure how this area is called, so I provided an additional screen
[image]

I've already excluded it from Doc and cmd-Tab Application Switcher but I didn't find what is the way to get rid of the icon from macOS status bar.

- macOS verion: 10.15.7
- iTerm2 version: 3.4.4

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works for iTerm2 version: 3.4.4:
**Prefs > Advanced > Add status bar icon when excluded from dock**

Comment: Didn't work for me the first time. I had to restart iTerm.

Answer (score 1):

From Preferences → Appearance

> #### Exclude from Dock and Cmd-Tab Application Switcher
>
> When this setting is enabled, iTerm2 will disappear from the dock and you won't be able to switch to it with Cmd-Tab. **An icon will be added to the right side of the menu bar** that lets you get back to iTerm2's preferences. This is useful if you only use hotkey windows and you want iTerm2 to keep a low profile.

https://iterm2.com/documentation-preferences-appearance.html (emphasis mine)

With that setting enabled the icon is added.

Comment: So there is no way to disable 2 options at the same time: exclude from the Dock and from the status menu?

Comment: damn't. that's really dolefully. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: If you removed both - how would you switch to iTerm?

Comment: @mmmmmm with my shortcut. I actually use the only shortcut and I have not ever used this icon in the status menu

Comment: @iamtodor What shortcut?

Comment: @mmmmmm in my case I chose cmd+I. Here is the screen https://imgur.com/a/CuWvM1i